# Vbscript - Read ini or text file for specific section

Tags: vbscript, ini

I want to store some addresses in a text file and then read specific portions of the file, based on group membership. I've done all of the group membership stuff so I don't need any help for that.

But I'm not sure if I should use a plain text file or an INI file?
The thing is, the post addresses are in two or three lines and I need line break.
I tried using a plain text file, but I couldn't manage to get a line break correctly.

So INI files would be preferable?

The INI file could look like this:

```
[London]
Address 1
Postbox 3245
58348 London

[Copenhagen]
Address 2
Postbox 2455
5478347 Copenhagen
```

I'm not quite sure if this is possible in an INI file though, perhaps I need to name each line as well. OR, I could possibly use a plain text file and search for the word [london] and then read each line until there's a line break. Then store all of those lines in a variable that I'll pass along?

How would you guys solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use CSV file instead where each row will represent a country.

```
Country,Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4
London,Address 1,Postbox 3245,58348 London
Copenhagen,Address 2,Postbox 2455,5478347,Copenhagen
```

If you can easily identify your data then you could probably have more descriptive column names (i.e. Street1, Street2, Town, Postcode, etc.).

This file format is also easy to read since you only read one line of the input file at a time and split it using something like

```
aAddress = split(sLine, ",")
```

To make it even easier to work with you could use dictionary object and use country as a key and array as a value

```
'sLine should be read from input file'
sLine = "Copenhagen,Address 2,Postbox 2455,5478347,Copenhagen"

'Create dictionary for addresses'
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Split line into array'
aAddressParts = Split(sLine, ",") 

'Remove the first element of the array'
sValues = Mid(sLine, InStr(sLine, ",")+1)
aValues = Split(sValues, ",")

'Add new entry into dictionary'
dic.Add aAddressParts(0), aValues

'Usage'
MsgBox "Address for Copenhagen: " & vbNewLine & _
    Join(dic("Copenhagen"), "," & vbNewLine)
```

Thanks,
Maciej

Comment: Good idea :) The whole idea about this all is that a client has to be able to edit the data easily, in a readable format. CSV can be opened with Excel. Great tip! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have written a small VBScript Class that handles "real' ini files written with such format:

```
[section_name]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
```

The code for the class is:

```vbs
Class IniFileObject
    Private m_Data

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        Set m_Data = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate
        Dim key
        If IsObject(m_Data) Then
            For Each key In m_Data
                m_Data(key).RemoveAll
                Set m_Data(key) = Nothing
            Next
            m_Data.RemoveAll
            Set m_Data = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function Init(sFilePath)
        Dim arrLines, sLine, x
        Dim sCurSection, oSectionDict
        Set Init = Me
        arrLines = GetFileLines(sFilePath)
        If Not(IsArray(arrLines)) Then Exit Function
        sCurSection = ""
        For x = 0 To UBound(arrLines)
            sLine = Trim(arrLines(x))
            If Len(sLine)>0 Then
                If Left(sLine, 1)="[" Then
                    If Not(HandleSectionLine(sLine, sCurSection)) Then Exit Function
                Else  
                    If Len(sCurSection)=0 Then
                        Err.Raise 1005, "IniFileObject init", "Found value outside any section (" & Server.HTMLEncode(sLine) & ")"
                        Exit Function
                    End If

                    Set oSectionDict = m_Data(sCurSection)
                    If Not(ParseOneLine(sLine, oSectionDict)) Then Exit Function
                    Set m_Data(sCurSection) = oSectionDict
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Function

    Public Property Get ReadValue(section, key)
        Dim oSectionDict
        ReadValue = ""
        If m_Data.Exists(section) Then
            Set oSectionDict = m_Data(section)
            If oSectionDict.Exists(key) Then ReadValue = oSectionDict(key)
        End If
    End Property

    Private Function ParseOneLine(ByVal sLine, ByRef oSectionDict)
        Dim arrTemp, sErrorMsg, sKey
        sErrorMsg = ""
        ParseOneLine = True
        If Left(sLine, 2)="//" Or Left(sLine, 1)="'" Or Left(sLine, 1)="{" Then Exit Function
        arrTemp = Split(sLine, "=")
        If UBound(arrTemp)=1 Then
            sKey = Trim(arrTemp(0))
            If (Len(sKey)>0) And (Len(arrTemp(1))>0) Then
                If Not(oSectionDict.Exists(sKey)) Then
                    oSectionDict.Add sKey, Trim(arrTemp(1))
                Else  
                    sErrorMsg = "Key already exists"
                End If
            Else  
                sErrorMsg = "Empty key or value"
            End If
        Else  
            sErrorMsg = "Missing or too much '=' characters"
        End If
        Erase arrTemp
        If Len(sErrorMsg)>0 Then
            ParseOneLine = False
            Err.Raise 1006, "IniFileObject Init", "Failed to parse single line (" & Server.HTMLEncode(sLine) & "): " & sErrorMsg
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function HandleSectionLine(ByVal sLine, ByRef sCurSection)
        HandleSectionLine = False
        If (Len(sLine)<3) Or (Right(sLine, 1)<>"]") Then
            Err.Raise 1002, "IniFileObject init", "Invalid line found: " & Server.HTMLEncode(sLine)
            Exit Function
        End If

        sCurSection = Mid(sLine, 2, Len(sLine) - 2)
        If m_Data.Exists(sCurSection) Then
            Err.Raise 1003, "IniFileObject init", "Section exists more than once: " & Server.HTMLEncode(sCurSection)
            Exit Function
        End If

        m_Data.Add sCurSection, Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        HandleSectionLine = True
    End Function

    Private Function GetFileLines(sFilePath)
        Dim objFSO, oFile
        Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not(objFSO.FileExists(sFilePath)) Then
            Set objFSO = Nothing
            Err.Raise 1001, "IniFileObject init", "file path '" & Server.HTMLEncode(sFilePath) & "' does not exist, check permissions"
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set oFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFilePath)
        GetFileLines = Split(oFile.ReadAll, VBCrLf)
        oFile.Close
        Set oFile = Nothing
        Set objFSO = Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage example:

```vbs
Dim filePath, ini
filePath = Server.MapPath("config.ini")
Set ini = New IniFileObject.Init(filePath)
Response.Write("Value for 'Key001': " & ini.ReadValue("MySection", "Key001") & "<br />")
Set ini = Nothing
```

The code throw various errors when the file does not exist or contains invalid lines, the errors are pretty much clear. It's possible to "suppress" the errors and not display error page by using such code when consuming:

```
On Error Resume Next
    Set ini = New IniFileObject.Init(filePath)
    If Err.Number<>0 Then
        Response.Write("Error reading ini file")
    End If
On Error Goto 0
If IsObject(ini) Then
    Response.Write("Value for 'IP001': " & ini.ReadValue("IPaddress", "IP001") & "<br />")
    Set ini = Nothing
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the addresses in one line and use a special character, for example an underscore,  to indicate a line break. When you read the address, you just need to replace the special character with a line break.

> [London]
>   Address = "Postbox 3245_58348
>   London"
>
> [Copenhagen]
>   Address = "Postbox
>   2455_5478347 Copenhagen"

That allows you to store addresses with more lines or without a postbox line, as well. In my experience, information like *"our addresses **always** have exactly two lines and the first one is **always** a postbox"* is very often incorrect...

Comment: Try `Replace(ReadIni, "_", vbCrLf)`, without any quotes around `vbCrLf`.

Answer (score 0):

I use a small executable that launches native api for that: [GetPrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WritePrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725501(v=vs.85).aspx).

The executable is called like that:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set exec = sh.Exec("ini.exe get %APPDATA%\sth\file.ini ""Section name"" key")
sFirma1 = exec.StdOut.ReadLine
Call sh.Run("ini.exe set %APPDATA%\sth\file.ini ""Section name"" key set_value", 0)
```

See also [Running command line silently with VbScript and getting output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5690134/772981).

This is the code of the executable:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void usage()
{
  puts("ini <get>/<set> <file> <section> <key> <value>");
  exit(1);
}

int main(int cArg, char **aszArg)
{
  int iFile = 2;
  int iSection = 3;
  int iKey = 4;
  int iValue = 5;
  if (cArg < 5) usage();
  if (strcmp(aszArg[1], "get") != 0 && strcmp(aszArg[1], "set") != 0) usage();
  if (strcmp(aszArg[1], "set") == 0 && cArg < iValue + 1) usage();
  if (strcmp(aszArg[1], "set") == 0) {
    if (!WritePrivateProfileString(aszArg[iSection], aszArg[iKey],
                                   aszArg[iValue], aszArg[iFile]))
      puts("Failure in WriteProfileString.");
  } else {
    char buf[1000];
    buf[0] = 0;
    GetPrivateProfileString(
      aszArg[iSection], aszArg[iKey], "", buf, 999, aszArg[iFile]);
    puts(buf);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You need to compile it using a c compiler for Windows. I did it with gcc, but a free compiler from ms should also work. If [this page](http://jarek.katowice.pl/ownsoft-en/ini-prog-en) with a 32-bit executable is still available, you may give it a try, but on your own responsibility. Hackers already visited my site once.