# Best way of automating a Visual studio build on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, scripting, vbscript

I need to build a c++ program in Visual Studio on Windows every 24 hours (I belive this is called a kron job?), and then send an email if it fails. I can't download any software on this machine, so I think I will have to make do with what Windows XP and visual studio has to offer.

I found a VBScript online that sends an e mail, which works fine. Now I need to automate the build.

I though about writing the thing on vbs and setting it in schedueled tasks to run once a day. I don't have any experience with VBs.

Is this a good way of solvig this?  Any better ides?

Thanks!

Comment: The obvious answer would be to use a build server for such tasks :-)

Comment: Otherwise, invoking [`MSBuild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx) from a VBScript script shouldn't be [that hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690134/running-command-line-silently-with-vbscript-and-getting-output), either...

Comment: You could use the windows task schedular to .. Well.. Schedule the program to run

Comment: Are you using revision control?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `devenv.exe` to build a solution or a project.
`devenv.exe` has several command line switches that could be used to start a build.

For example, to build a `Release` configuration of a solution file called `myworkspace.sln` you would do the following - `devenv.exe myworkspace.sln /build Release`.

Here is the list of command line arguments supported by `devenv.exe` -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=vs.80).aspx

For the recurring task to be run every 24 hours, use the `Windows Task Scheduler` to create a recurring task which runs the `devenv.exe` command line shown above.

`Task scheduler` can be found in the `Administrative Tools` menu or you can run the command `taskschd.msc`.