# How to return PowerShell variable to VBScript

Tags: powershell, vbscript, hta

I have a vbscript to call a PowerShell script in hopes of returning the PowerShell output to an HTA (HTML Application) GUI. Right now I just want to see if I can return the PowerShell output into a MsgBox in the vbscript. I am not having much luck with this.

VBScript Code:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
return = shell.Run("powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -file pathToScript\PowerShellToVBA.ps1", , true)
MsgBox return
```

PowerShell Code:

```
Clear-Host
return 50
```

I am trying to keep the return value extremely simple until it works. With this,  I would expect the MsgBox to return '50', however it is returning '0' instead. Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: I think 0 is the exit code of powershell execution, stand for success. Seems your `return` pulled the status of the execution. You can do `exit 50` in powershell but I don't think this is the legit way of doing things.

Comment: You can take a look at this ==> [Get Output of a PowerShell Script in a HTA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198533/get-output-of-a-powershell-script-in-a-hta/35267951#35267951)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you just want the *exit* command to get the return value:

**VBScript**

```
pscommand = ".\myscript.ps1; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
cmd = "powershell.exe -noprofile -command " & pscommand
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
rv = shell.Run(cmd, , True)
MsgBox "PowerShell returned: " & rv, vbSystemModal
```

**Powershell**

```
exit 50;
```

**EDIT #1**

Or if you want to grab a return *string*:

**VBScript**

```
pscommand = ".\myscript2.ps1"
cmd = "powershell.exe -noprofile -command " & pscommand
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set executor = shell.Exec(cmd)
executor.StdIn.Close
MsgBox executor.StdOut.ReadAll
```

**Powershell**

```
Write-Output '***SUCCESS***';
```

Comment: Sweet, that got it to return 50! Now does this only work with numeric values? I changed the exit to a string value and it doesn't work

Comment: Exit only supports integer return values but you could just grab the output. I've expanded my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup, using the VBScript above to output a string. In your PS script if you use eg

`write-host "Error: some specific thing happened"`

to set various error or success messages the

`MsgBox executor.StdOut.ReadAll`

will display all of what you write via write-host.

A helpful way to display the outcome of the PS script to your VBA user.

Just FYI.