# Return a object or list of objects from Powershell to VBScript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm working on a script in VBScript (inside Sparx EA) to validate the users and groups of an Azure Entra ID (aka Azure AD)

Now since it seems to be much easier to use Powershell to get that information from Azure, I wrote a powershell script and execute that from VBScript like this:

```
dim shell
set shell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
shell.run "powershell -file " & script.FullPath
```

My powershell script creates a number of CSV files containing the info I need.
When the powershell script is finished, I read those files in VBScript.

```
dim groups
set groups = getGroupsFromFile(script.FullPathWithoutExtension & "_AzureADGroups.csv")
dim users
set users = getUsersFromFile(script.FullPathWithoutExtension & "_AzureADUsers.csv")
'link users with groups
readMembershipsFromFile script.FullPathWithoutExtension & "_AzureADUserGroups.csv", users, groups
```

Then I cleanup by deleting the CSV files created by my Powershell script.

Instead of this workaround with the CSV files, I would much rather get a list of user objects in VBScript, but I haven't found a way to do that.

I know it's possible to return an integer using the exit command, or a string using the StdOut from this question:  [How to return PowerShell variable to VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941027/how-to-return-powershell-variable-to-vbscript)

But I haven't found a way to return objects or lists of objects from Powershell to VBScript.

Comment: Change the PowerShell script to use `ConvertTo-Csv` instead of `Export-Csv` - then read the CSV contents directly from standard output

Comment: Short answer - you can't pass PowerShell / dotnet object references across process boundaries. Even powershell remoting uses an interim serialization format and the "received" objects are sometimes just synthetic propertybags rather than "real" objects - see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/how-objects-are-sent-to-and-from-remote-sessions/. The best you could do is maybe serialize (e.g. ```ConvertTo-Csv``` or json / xml) the output in PowerShell, send it to StdOut with ```write-host``` and receive / reconstruct it again from StdIn inside the VBScript code per your linked answer.

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen and @ mclayton for the suggestion. Since I need several differents sets of data the current workaround using CSV files seems OK.  BTW "This is not possible because..." is also an answer, so if you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Why not rewrite the vbs in powershell ?

Comment: @Civette because Sparx EA's scripting environment doesn't support powershell. And even then; rewriting thousands of lines of scripts isn't a job I would look forward too.