# How do I make output selectable in HTA

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I am trying to make a simple HTA to run queries on Active Directory and then the output would be selectable options. The part I am unable to figure out is how to make the selections portion.

```
Sub User
    set objExec = objshell.Exec(dsquery user -name "UserName")
    set objStdOut = objExec.StdOut
    strLine = objStdOut.ReadAll
    Results.value = StrLine
End Sub
```

This code will output to a textarea.

```
<textarea name="Results">
```

Which I would then like to be selectable options. So if for example I have multiple users with the name 'Smith' then I can select the one I want and run another query with that information.

If there is a better solution than a textarea I am open to sugestions. I just dont want it to be a dropdown or radio button.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you mean something like this ??? ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198533/get-output-of-a-powershell-script-in-a-hta/35267951#35267951

Comment: @Hackoo
Basically what I am looking for is this
    dsquery user -name "smith*"
will return 2 users
  Smith, John
  Smith, Mike
I want to be able to click on 1 and have it select that user to run another command

Answer (score 1):

This an example from **[How Can I Dynamically Populate a List Box in an HTA ?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/08/15/how-can-i-dynamically-populate-a-list-box-in-an-hta/)**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Local Users</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
     ID="objHTAHelpomatic"
     APPLICATIONNAME="LocalUsers"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
>
</head>
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
    Sub Window_Onload
        Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
        strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName
        Set colAccounts = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "")
        colAccounts.Filter = Array("user")
        For Each objUser In colAccounts
            Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
            objOption.Text = objUser.Name
            objOption.Value = objUser.Name
            LocalUsers.Add(objOption)
        Next
    End Sub
'*********************************************************************
Sub Execute()
    Dim UserVar,ws
    UserVar = LocalUsers.value
    Command = "cmd /k Title Execution of NET USER for "& DblQuote(UserVar) &" & net user "& UserVar &""
    set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.run Command
End Sub
'*********************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*********************************************************************
</SCRIPT>
<body>
Command Net User<br><br>
    <select name="LocalUsers"></select>
    <input type="button" value="Execute Command Net User" onclick="Execute()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is the type of selection I want.Now I am trying to figure out how I can reference the option selected to run a command on just the 1 selection.

Comment: I think that will work. I will try it out and let you know. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user3527088 check my last edit, i added a button to execute the command !