# Getting the return value from a cmd /c command in VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript

In VBScript, the built-in `Shell.Run` method does not provide for output redirection, so the following workaround must be used:

[Running command line silently with VbScript and getting output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690134/running-command-line-silently-with-vbscript-and-getting-output)

```
Dim retVal
retVal = WshShell.Run( "cmd /c ""commandGoesHere"" > c:\temp\output.txt", 0, True )
```

However `returnValue` will have the return value of `cmd`, not of `commandGoesHere`.

I thought I could check `shell.Environment("ERRORLEVEL")` but presumably this would also be `cmd`'s return value, and not `commandGoesHere`.

...so how can I get `commandGoesHere`'s return value *and* simultaneously redirect its output to another file?

Comment: I hope that's pseudo code because you can't assign variables like that in VBScript, closest you can get is `Dim returnValue : returnValue = ...`.

Answer (score 3):

```vbs
returnValue = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run( _ 
    "cmd /v /c (>""output.txt"" ""commandGoesHere"" & exit !errorlevel!)" _ 
    , 0 _ 
    , True _ 
)
```

Start the `cmd` instance with delayed expansion enabled (`/v`) and exit the `cmd` instance with the `errorlevel` set by the previous command.

Delayed expansion is needed because the `cmd` parser replaces all `%var%` read operations with the value inside the variables during the line/block parse phase. Without delayed expansion (`%errorlevel%`), the value to be returned by the `exit` command will be retrived before starting to execute the command. With delayed expansion (`!errorlevel!`) the value will be retrieved when the `exit` command is executed, after the `commandGoesHere` has ended.