# Process.Start(processInfo) response is blank

Tags: c#, .net

I need to invoke an exe using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processInfo)` and want to get some value return back.Based on return value i need to perform further operation. Exe is getting invoked and performing the task accurately, but i am not able to get return value back. Code gets stuck after `process.Start()` no exception or warning.

```
string arguments = arg[0]+ " " + arg[1] + " " + arg[2] + " " + arg[3];
string consoleExePath = @"C:\Test\Console.exe";
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
processInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(consoleExePath);
processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/c START {0} {1}", Path.GetFileName(consoleExePath), arguments);
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processInfo);
var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
int result = p.ExitCode; // always 0
```

Code inside exe:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
  var flag = 0;
  flag=   objTest.DoSomething(args[0],args[1], args[2], args[3]);
  //Console.WriteLine("Process completed!");
  //Console.Read();
  //return flag;
  return 44; // a non zero value.
}
```

Edit: Due to `Console.Read();`, code execution got stuck. thanks to schnaader for catching the silly mistake. But `var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` is still empty. tried  `int result = p.ExitCode;` and `result` is always `0`.

Comment: The .exe code calls `Console.Read()` which will wait for the user to enter a line, and only exit after that - did you take that into account?

Comment: You're not launching your exe - you're launching `cmd.exe` which in turn is launching your exe, for some reason. The console process completed successfully and returned `0`. It doesn't pass back the return code of whatever *it* last executed.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever : could you suggest the changes required?

Comment: That depends - presumably, at some earlier point you had `.FileName = consoleExePath` and `.Arguments = arguments`. What, specifically, were you doing that made you decide to put `cmd` in the middle?

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever : I am trying it without `cmd` . I ll post here abt it. Thanks.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever : it worked, i removed `cmd`. Though `var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` still return blank value, but  `p.ExitCode` returns the hard coded 'integer' value. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me. Note that in your .exe code, there is a line:

```
Console.Read();
```

So the program will wait for the user to enter a line, and only exit after that. If you don't do this, the other code will wait for the application to terminate like you described.

So you should remove that line and try again.

Another possibility that Christian.K noted in the comments is to redirect standard input using `processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true`. This way, you won't have to modify the .exe code. After that, you can redirect things to the standard input of your .exe, see [MSDN for a full example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Alternatively, he could just use `RedirectStandardInput = true;` and then later, after `Start()`, `p.StandardInput.Close();`.

Comment: schnaader : Thanks, it was a very silly mistake. But still output is blank. i supposed to get integer value back. could you help again?

Comment: @AStacker: The process exit code (the `flag` in the .exe code) is available in `p.ExitCode` after the `p.WaitForExit()` call.

Comment: schnaader: p.ExitCode  returns 0 always. Even i have hard coded the return value to non-zero.

Comment: Ah, you're running "cmd /c start {0} {1}" which doesn't adopt the exit code from console.exe. Try running your exe directly, e.g. `processInfo.FileName = @"C:\Test\Console.exe"` and `processInfo.Arguments = arguments`

Comment: Another possible approach could be this answer, but I don't know how to adapt this to C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778613/getting-the-return-value-from-a-cmd-c-command-in-vbscript

Comment: schnaader : it worked, i removed `cmd`. Though `var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` still return blank value, but  `p.ExitCode` returns the hard coded `integer` value. Thanks.