# Invoke Windows Call command without starting a new console window

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I am trying to call 2 commands together using windows command `call`. The commands are invoked from a vbscript file. `Cscript` command is used to run the vbscript file. When I run the .vbs file from the cmd a new cmd window is shown. Is there any way to avoid this? I am thinking some thing like `start /B` for `call` command. My vbscript given below.

```
DIM BuildExecuteString
BuildExecuteString = "cmd /c call ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"" & devenv ""Test.sln"" /Rebuild ""Release|Any CPU"" /project ""Test"""

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Call objShell.Run(BuildExecuteString, 1, True)
```

Comment: Did you try changing the intWindowStyle `1` _(activate and display the window)_ setting, to `0` _(hide the window)_?

Comment: Setting WindowStyle to 0 hides the window. I don't want that, I want the outputs from the launched applications to be displayed in the same cmd in which the vbscript is invoked.

Comment: If the vbscript is running already running via cscript.exe inside a cmd.exe window, why are you opening another instance of cmd.exe? In fact why are you wanting to run a batch file via vbscript? Can you not simply run `Call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"...` directly?

Comment: without `cmd /c` i get error `t.vbs(5, 1) (null): The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Perhaps the `BuildExecuteString` should be defined like `BuildExecuteString = "cmd /c call """"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"" & devenv ""Test.sln"" /Rebuild ""Release|Any CPU"" /project ""Test"""""`...

Comment: @FaisalM, I told you to not use vbscript/cscript at all, you're obviously running that from a batch file, so don't, just replace the vbscript stuff completely by `call`ing `VSDevCmd` with your specific arguments.

Comment: I cannot omit the vbscript as I have some file processing (to update the build versions) before invoking this vs commands.

Comment: @aschipfl using the command 'call' always brings a new cmd window.

Comment: No, [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) does not! Anyway, my comment targeted at the quotation...

Comment: @aschipfl For me, invoking `call` command from VBScript always brings a new cmd window.

Answer (score 0):

```
Call objShell.Run(BuildExecuteString, 0, True)
```

The 1, 0, etc is the windowStyle (how it should run):

[See how the run command works](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html)

Comment: 0 options hides the new cmd window so the outputs from the new window wont be displayed. I want the output is to be shown in the same cmd. My problem is with the `call` command which always show a new window.

Comment: You can't output the execution in the same CMD. As an alternative you could output what the batch file does in a TXT and read it after execution, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690134/running-command-line-silently-with-vbscript-and-getting-output