# how to read ini file using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vbscript - Read ini or text file for specific section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491965/vbscript-read-ini-or-text-file-for-specific-section)

I am trying to check whether IPaddress of other PC can be accessed or not.
If IPaddress is static, following code is ok.

**vbscript code**

```
Dim Shell, strCommand, strHost, ReturnCode
strHost = "192.168.10.1"
Set Shell = wscript.createObject("wscript.shell")
strCommand = "ping -n 1 -w 300 " & strHost
ReturnCode = Shell.Run(strCommand, 0, True)
If ReturnCode = 0 Then
wscript.echo strHost & " is pingable"
Else
wscript.echo strHost & " is not pingable"
End If
```

As I want to check dynamic IPaddress, use ini file.

**ini file**

```
[IPaddress]
IP001 = "192.168.10.1";
IP002 = "192.168.10.2";
```

Now, I would like to know how to connect ini file and vbscript code.
Please explain it to me.

Comment: There is no built in functionality in VBScript for this - the only way is using plain FSO and parse the file yourself.

Comment: A useful project for that: [INI Reader / Writer Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/VB_NET_INIFile_Object.aspx)

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491965/vbscript-read-ini-or-text-file-for-specific-section/7469754#7469754) it should handle what you need and is pretty flexible, better for the future if you'll have changes in the INI file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shadow Wizard mentions in his comment, you'll need to use [FSO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (FileSystemObject) to read the file. The sample code for [OpenTextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would probably be a good place to begin.

If you move your current vbscript code into a [Sub](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_procedures.asp) that accepts one ip address as the argument you can just call that sub for each ip address in the file.

Maybe something like this (completely untested code):

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)
Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    line = MyFile.ReadLine
    If Left(line, 2) = "IP" Then
        ipAddress = Replace(Replace(Right(line, 8), ";", ""), """", "") 
        YourSubThatPings ipAddress
    End If
Loop
MyFile.Close
```

The code that gets out the `ipAddress` from the `line` probably needs to be rewritten to be a bit more flexible though. And if the ini file contains a lot of other data maybe you need to add some code to skip to the correct section etc.